# Library cannot have Implementation-Version set, without also specifying its Specification-Version (Weblogic)

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

When, from **Spring Tool Suite**, I run a little web application (created with **Spring boot**) on **Weblogic 12** the application works.

When I "install" the **WAR** file on Weblogic, by using **Weblogic console** (localhost:7001/console) I get this error:

```
weblogic.application.library.LibraryDeploymentException: 
[J2EE:160144]Failed to register library Extension-Name: projectwar, 
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Library cannot have 
Implementation-Version set, without also specifying its Specification-Version
```

How can I specified a **Specification-Version**? What it means?
Thank you guys.

Comment: Be sure to deploy your application as a web application and not as a shared library. The question is asked by the console when you deploy the application.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin thank you!!!

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to deploy your application as a web application and not as a shared library. The question is asked by the console when you deploy the application